# Debug HTTPS errors

Tags: ssl, https

When accessing my site, the SSL session is successful while the page loads.
A few seconds after the page loaded FireFox shows that SSL is no longer available.

I am guessing its some script (all I have is Google Analytics and Facebook).
How can I see what caused FireFox (or IE/Chrome) to drop the SSL and why ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried firebug? It should show you what is going on.

Comment: Not sure how to use Firebug for that. There is nothing on the console to see.

Comment: see network if you are getting redirected or what elements are loaded. There you can also see if they come from https or not.